# system verilog- Mail Box

Tags: system-verilog

Below I have posted the complete code for mailbox. It has a class Generator, class Driver and there is a top level code. My question is in the below code, inside Class Generator, how Transation tr and mailbox mbx are used? Also, in function new how mbx is used?

```
program mailbox_example(bus_if.TB bus...);
  class Generator;   // Class Generator
    Transaction tr;
    mailbox mbx;

    function new (mailbox mbx);
      this.mbx=mbx;
    endfunction

    task run;
      repeat (10) begin
        tr=new;
        assert(tr.randomize);
        mbx.put(tr); //send out transaction
      end
    endtask
  endclass

  class Driver;  //Class Driver
    Transaction tr;
    mailbox mbx;

    function new(mailbox mbx);
      this.mbx=mbx;
    endfunction

    task run;
      repeat(10) begin
        mbx.get(tr);
        @(posedge busif.cb.ack);
        bus.cb.kind<=tr.kind;
        ...
      end
    endtask
  endclass

  mailbox mbx;  //Top level
  Generator gen;
  Driver drv;
  initial begin
    mbx=new;
    gen=new(mbx);
    drv=new(mbx);
    fork
      gen.run();
      drv.run();
    join
  end
endprogram
```

Comment: BTW, I strongly recommend that you use a parameterized mailbox with type of object you plan to pass through the mailbox. `mailbox #(Transaction) mbx` This lets the compiler type-check the objects that you put/get from the mailbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailbox is a medium, used to communicate between two blocks.

**Why mailbox is in constructor..??**
To communicate between two blocks, like driver and generator, there should be a common mailbox between them (like a common cable is used to carry information from DTH antenna to set-top box).
To share a common mailbox between Driver and Generator, the mailbox is instantiated in top level block (e.g. Env) and its handle is passed to the driver and generator through a constructor.

**How transaction and mailbox are used?**
A mailbox has default methods to store and get transactions like put(), try_put(), get(), try_get(), peek() and try_peek(). In generator, the transaction is stored into mailbox using put() or try_put() method. In driver, the transaction is retrieved using get(), try_get(), peek() or try_peek() method.

Please refer Section *15.4 Mailboxes* in SV LRM for more details. :)

Comment: Inside "function new(mailbox mbx)", what does "this.mbx=mbx;" means? Also, Inside "task run;" what does "tr=new;" means?

Comment: It means you need find some resource to lean SystemVerilog, especially class basics. Sorry but trying to explain this basic concept in a forum would be to broad a topic.